# Nginx setup for Wordpress does not link posts correctly

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting, configuration-files, permalinks

I currently have a WordPress site, which is currently installed on a subdirectory. However, there seems to be an issue.

The site appears as it supposed to, but the posts are either having a 404 error page and redirecting to the root of the site. Here is the screenshot of the setup I currently have on the server:

[image: Please have a look at the setup I currently have on the server.]

If anyone can please help me out here. I would appreciate it.

UPDATE (29/04/2018):

I have been working on this and it has come to a point where the blog page opens however, the posts are coming up with a 404 error message from the ROOT site.

For example:
When opening the subdirectory ( `example.com/blog` ), the site will appear. When clicking on a post, the 404 page will be displayed, but on the `example.com` site.

This makes me believe that there is an issue with the 2 WordPress installations however, I cannot be certain.

Here are my Nginx configurations for the root and the blog:

```
        location /blog {
            root /var/www/html/aus;
            index index.php index.html;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.error.log;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^.*$ /blog/index.php last;
            }
        }

        location / {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/root.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/root.error.log;

            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            gzip off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
            reset_timedout_connection on;

            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't show your configuration as the image but as a code.

Comment: @timiTao Sorry for this. I will show it as code next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 404 error page or some other error for posts, reset your permalinks setting.

Go to Settings → Permalinks and reset it to default settings and save it.

[image: Permalinks setting]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and this seems to come up with the same error. I could imagine that it’s a rewrite issue?

Comment: Try to add default htaccess code by referring this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) and then check for the 404 error.

Comment: I have also added the default htaccess however, this does not do anything on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx config should be something like this:

upstream php-upstream {
                server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock fail_timeout=0;
        }

```
    ...

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
            reset_timedout_connection on;

            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    ...
```

That's an excerpt from a working nginx config for a wordpress website. Of course you should adapt it and modify it accordingly to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this tip @bogdan. 

I have tried this however, it still does not seem to work. Is this correct:

location /blog/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
            <your code you mentioned above>
  
  }
}

Comment: Hi @bogdan.

Thanks for your response. I have found a solution towards the issue now which is appearing fine. I am now having an issue where some posts are linking to the root server instead of the sub-directory. Would this be a rewrite issue?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary a rewrite issue but rather the links are like that in the database. You should probably check the entries in your website's db and modify them to suit your needs

Comment: I have looked into the entries in the db however, they seem to be correct. There are some posts in Wordpress that goes to the correct subfolder post. But there are some posts that go to the root URL (which are wrong). Any other possible suggestions?